# Hide messages from particular users

Tags: javascript

The code below should hide messages from John, Mike, and guest users. For some reason, I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null` error message. How to fix it?

I don't work with JavaScript often, so I think the error is probably trivial, but its not easy to spot it myself.

```js
var list_of_blocked = ["john", "mike"];
var style_filter = 'blur(4pt)';

document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach((e) => {
  var e_speaker = e.querySelector('a[itemprop=creator]');
  var is_author_guest = e.querySelector('div.sign').innerText.startsWith('guest');
  if (!e_speaker && !is_author_guest) {
    return;
  }

  var speaker = e_speaker.innerText;
  if (!list_of_blocked.includes(speaker)) {
    return;
  }

  e.style.filter = style_filter;
});
```

```html
<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by john</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">john</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by mike</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">mike</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by guest</p>
  <div class="sign">guest</div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by jane</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">jane</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: are you retrieving the `element` in `e_speaker` when checked in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `e_speaker` exists, also I improved your code with ES6

```js
const list_of_blocked = ["john", "mike"];
const style_filter = 'blur(4pt)';

document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach(el => {
  const e_speaker = el.querySelector('a[itemprop=creator]')

  if (e_speaker) {
    const speaker = e_speaker.innerText;
    const is_author_guest = el.querySelector('div.sign').innerText.startsWith('guest')

    if (!e_speaker && !is_author_guest || !list_of_blocked.includes(speaker)) return;
  }
    el.style.filter = style_filter;

});
```

```html
<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by john</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">john</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by mike</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">mike</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by guest</p>
  <div class="sign">guest</div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by jane</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">jane</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

just check for null:

```js
var list_of_blocked = ["john", "mike"];
var style_filter = 'blur(4pt)';

document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach((e) => {
  var e_speaker = e.querySelector('a[itemprop=creator]');
  var is_author_guest = e.querySelector('div.sign').innerText.startsWith('guest');
  if (!e_speaker && !is_author_guest) {
    return;
  }

if(e_speaker){
  var speaker = e_speaker.innerText;
  if (!list_of_blocked.includes(speaker)) {
    return;
  }
  }

  e.style.filter = style_filter;
});
```

```html
<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by john</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">john</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by mike</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">mike</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by guest</p>
  <div class="sign">guest</div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by jane</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">jane</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

**Update :**

Much nicer with jQuery:

```js
var list_of_blocked = ["john", "mike"];

$( 'article' ).each(function(article) {
          if($(this).children("div:contains('guest')").get(0)){
                $(this).css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
              $(this).css({'filter':'blur(1pt)'});
          }else{          
            var aCreator =$(this).find("div > a[itemprop='creator']");            
            if(aCreator.length){
                 // console.log($(aCreator).text());        
               if(list_of_blocked.includes($(aCreator).text())){
                     $(this).css({"color": "blue", "border": "2px solid blue"});
                     $(this).css({'filter':'blur(1pt)'});
               }
            }else{
                    console.log("unknown node type!")
            }
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by john</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">john</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by mike</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">mike</a>
  </div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by guest</p>
  <div class="sign">guest</div>
</article>

<article itemscope="itemscope">
  <p>message text by jane</p>
  <div class="sign">
    <a itemprop="creator">jane</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery version :) As you probably guessed, the code in my question is a part of a userscript. Although jQuery is useful in many cases, I prefer to avoid using it when there is no significant difference in how complex the code is. My current working version is somewhat between your initial solution and the solution by @dippas. And it seems it works perfectly :)

Comment: what is the problem with my solution? I answered first....  :)

Comment: No problems at all. It was posted at 2021-02-19 15:18:00Z and the other answer was posted just one minute later, at 2021-02-19 15:19:31Z. The second answer have some improvements over my original code rather than just a fix of the issue, so I decided to accept that one. As for the jQuery solution, it is just somewhat out of scope of my initial intentions.